# Is the Kendo-style fight in Dark Matter episode 6 the same as in episode 9?

Tags: dark-matter

In episode 6 of Dark Matter, Five is drawn into Four's memory of a Kendo-style fight with his brother. This fight is repeated in episode 9 but a different actor plays the part of young Four. The part of the fight with the actors wearing masks can obviously be used in both episodes, but I want to know if the non-masked fight between Five/young Four and the emperor is exactly the same. Since I can't run the episodes in tandem I was wondering if anyone else could find out if this is true.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to use VLC media player on my computer to slow down the episodes one by one and take notes. Here are the results for the dialogue and fight scenes. It turns out that they are pretty different!

Emperor: Why did you hesitate?

Four:

> Keeps his eyes on the floor. “I had already won the point. There was no need to strike, father.”

Five:

> Stares into the Emperor’s face. “I won the point. There was no need to strike.”

Emperor: What is it you think you’re learning here?

Four:

> “Swordsmanship father.”

Five

> “Swordsmanship. Father.”

Emperor: No, you’re learning discipline.

*Five's fight scene*:

> - Five holds her stick out parallel to the ground to block the Emperor’s overhead strike
> - She swings her stick down on the right-hand side but is blocked
> - She blocks a strike on the right-hand side
> - She ducks under a left-hand strike (although in fast-motion it looks like the Emperor hits her and the fight stops)

*Four's fight scene*:

> - Four swings his stick from lower-left to block the Emperor's upper-right strike.
> - He swings down on the right-hand side but is blocked.
> - The camera focuses on the Emperor so we don't see anything until he swings his stick at Four's left-hand side.
> - Four looks as though he's been hit on the left shoulder and spins to the right but is actually beyond the reach of the Emperor's stick.

Emperor: You're learning to respect our ways and traditions.

*Five's fight scene:*

> - Five swings her stick from lower-right to the center
> - She blocks a downward strike on the left and momentum carries her forward on the left-hand side past the Emperor.
> - She turns to the left and is hit on the right shoulder which makes her stumble away from the Emperor.
> - She spins back around to the left

*Four's fight scene:*

> - The Emperor swings from Four's lower-left to upper-right which he blocks.
> - The Emperor feints to Four's lower-left and as Four moves to block, the Emperor strikes at his face. Four turns to the right as if he is hit and staggers downwards.
> - Four gets up and turns to his right, coming to face the Emperor.

Emperor: When you are Emperor, and your enemies find you vulnerable, do you think they will hesitate?

*Five's fight scene:*

> - Five lunges towards the Emperor with an overhead strike on the right-hand side.
> - The Emperor blocks the strike
> - Five strikes upwards from the lower left and is blocked
> - The Emperor turns in a circle to the right and blocks Five's downward strike on the right-hand side
> - Five tries another downward right-hand strike but is hit across the stomach with a sideways strike from the Emperor
> - She staggers up and strikes from mid to low right but is blocked.

The action is blocked by a pillar and when we can see...

> - Five's stick is being forced up on the right-hand side by the Emperor's stick until it completes a full circle.
> - The Emperor lifts his stick and hits Five across the face from the lower-right.
> - Five collapses to the ground on her hands and knees, blood coming from her lower-right lip.

*Four's fight scene:*

> - Four goes for a direct overhead strike which is blocked by the Emperor swinging his stick up towards Four's right.
> - Four strikes upwards from his lower-left to upper-right but misses the Emporer.
> - From behind the Emperor we see him swing hard across Four's middle from the left-hand side. Four grunts but...
> - swings his stick from the lower-right but is blocked by the Emperor's lower-left strike.
> - Four swings his stick in a circle from right to left but is blocked on the lower-left.
> - The Emperor brings the other side of his stick around and appears to strike Four on the right-hand side of his face.
> - Four spins to the right and falls to one knee, facing away from the Emperor.
> - The Emperor turns and walks out.
> - Four turns to the right and stands up. He appears to be untouched (no blood).

*End*